# BrightCove video stuck while playing in IPad

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, brightcove

I have this java script that I use to display a video on a website. The video launches and plays fine on the website.
But when I insert the same javascript and put it in the string and try to load the video on an iPad Simulator, it gets stuck. Am I doing something wrong?

Code

```
NSMutableString *playerString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
        [playerString appendString:@"<!-- Start of Brightcove Player --> <div style=\"display:none\"> </div> <!-- By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. --> <script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js\"></script> <object id=\"myExperience1778612770001\" class=\"BrightcoveExperience\"> <param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#FFFFFF\" /> <param name=\"width\" value=\"480\" /> <param name=\"height\" value=\"270\" /> <param name=\"playerID\" value=\"1776746869001\" /> <param name=\"playerKey\" value=\"AQ~~,AAABnWrZAiE~,vOZcyTPVgHpcrcOyFdRZXnunkRSWEVpt\" /> <param name=\"isVid\" value=\"true\" /> <param name=\"isUI\" value=\"true\" /> <param name=\"dynamicStreaming\" value=\"true\" /> <param name=\"@videoPlayer\" value=\"1778612770001\" /> </object> <!-- This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line. --> <script type=\"text/javascript\">brightcove.createExperiences();</script> <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->"];
        NSLog(@"\n------------Script :%@\n-----------------------", playerString);
//videoPlayer is the webview
        [self.videoPlayer loadHTMLString:playerString baseURL:nil];
```

[image: Player Stuck in iPad after hitting the play button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give the correct base url... that worked